# Behat Installation on Windows

Tags: php, behat

I have been installed behat in xampp (windows). I used a PEAR to install it. but when I am runing with console, its not work, because need some file on Symfony framework. the error message can see on this picture:
[image]

Comment: yes...it's require "ContainerBuilder.php"

Comment: post the errors with your question, are you trying to install behat extension (https://github.com/Behat/Symfony2Extension) ?

Comment: yeah...i am trying to install behat, but it need Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php 
and i don't know, how to configure it....:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To this day I have never been able to get behat to work in a windows environment. Consider spinning up an Ubuntu 32bit virtual machine and give it all a try there for the best experience with Behat. At this stage in it's development the windows support isn't there.